# WebView does not display HTML string content in Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, win-universal-app

I am trying to display static HTML content sent from previous Page as string to current Page when navigated to, in a Windows 10 Universal app.

I have following WebView in XAML which will display HTML content:

```
<Grid>    
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <WebView x:Name="NewsContent" ext:MyExtensions.HTML="{Binding Source={Binding Content}}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

C# portion:

```
public sealed partial class NewsItemView : Page
{
    WebLink link;

    public NewsItemView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        NewsContent.NavigateToString((e.Parameter as WebLink).Content); 
}
```

Helper class implementation:

```
public class MyExtensions
{
    public static string GetHTML(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(HTMLProperty);
    }

    public static void SetHTML(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(HTMLProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for HTML.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...  
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HTMLProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HTML", typeof(string), typeof(MyExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private static void OnHTMLChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebView wv = d as WebView;
        if (wv != null)
        {
            wv.NavigateToString((string)e.NewValue);
        }
    }
}
```

While debugging, the HTML content is available in (e.Parameter as WebLink).Content, but is not displayed in WebView.
Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is: StackPanel hides your webview. Put webview outside of the StackPanel should make it work.

Also you have problem with the extension:

Change

```
public static string GetHTML(DependencyObject obj)
public static void SetHTML(DependencyObject obj, string value)
public static readonly DependencyProperty HTMLProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HTML", typeof(string), typeof(MyExtensions), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

to

```
public static string GetHTML(WebView obj)
public static void SetHTML(WebView obj, string value)
public static readonly DependencyProperty HTMLProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HTML", typeof(string), typeof(MyExtensions), new PropertyMetadata("", OnHTMLChanged));
```

Comment: As a first step, I removed the StackPanel and it started working. So didn't make any changes in the extension code. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!

Comment: the problem with your extension is: it will not update web view when changing HTML property.

if you are fine with my answer, please mark it as answer. thank you

Comment: `StackPanel hides your webview. Put webview outside of the StackPanel should make it work.` - this sentence was the part that helped me.